# How to migrate my "Codenameone" Project from (java 5) to (Java 8)

Tags: codenameone

I read that CodenNameOne plugin will work only with Java 8 on 3.5 version.
My project is a big project with code writen in Java 5 with several components customized by myself.  It is a mix of Native-App with Web-App
(WebComponet + JavaScript Bridge + AngularJS, and so on).

Is there risk of breaking my code?

What I need to do to make a smooth transition to Java 8.

With the last version of plugin (3.4) can I write my code in Java8 at this moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say it will only work with Java 8 we mean as the underlying VM of the IDE and SDK. You don't need to activate the Java 8 functionality for your application if you don't want to.

You can use 3.4 and 3.3 targets with Java 8 support enabled.

If you do want to make use of Java 8 features do the steps outlined [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html):

- Add the `java.version=8` build hint
- Make sure the IDE and the project use Java 8
- In the build.xml replace usage of `1.5` with `1.8`

Comment: Hi Shai, Thanks for your comments. I'll follow your recommendations. But, Please, Might you give me additional information about this theme. Can I use all new features offered by Java 8 (sintaxe, all standard edition classes...). Is There documentation about which classes or features I can not use. Has Codenameone-SE different implementations for specifics classes when compared with respective classes distributed in Oracle Java 8 SE?

Comment: You can't use all the features. You can use only the API's listed in the javadocs https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/ Our original announcement detailed the missing features https://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html the biggest omission is streams which aren't supported. Since we use retrolambda internally the same limitations apply: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda